# How do I make a swift file with prewritten suggested methods?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've made a new swift file named "CustomSearchBar" that inherits from UISearchBar,

```
import UIKit

class CustomSearchBar : UISearchBar {

}
```

My question is, how do I fill this .swift file with the nice, pre-made suggested functions with Apple's included comments and such. I've seen it done before but can't quite remember.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not at a Mac currently, but IIRC when you first make the file, select iOS on the left -> Cocoa Touch Classes -> Swift File and select it to be a UISearchBar class. Sorry that this is not exact, but it is something similar to this and not difficult to figure out.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks Caleb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a new file choose `Cocoa Touch Class` not `Swift file`. From there, you can choose the new file to be subclass of `UISearchBar`. Xcode will generate some nice suggested functions and comment for you.